# ¿Cómo mostrar un ArrayList único de dos clases diferentes?

Tags: java, arraylist, herencia, polimorfismo

Estoy realizando un ejecicio en el que tengo herencia y polimorfismo sobre dos objetos CuentaCorriente y CuentaAhorro, voy a guardar en un mismo arrayList llamado cuenta que proviene de la clase abstracta CuentaBancaria.

```
static ArrayList <CuentaBancaria> cuenta = new ArrayList<CuentaBancaria>();
```

Es decir, en este arraylist añado por una parte los datos de cuenta corriente y por otra parte los datos de cuenta ahorro:

```
cuenta.add(new CuentaCorriente(numCuenta, ingreso));

cuenta.add(new CuentaAhorro(numCuenta, ingreso));
```

Si deseo ver en concreto la cuenta corriente o la cuenta ahorro ¿cómo lo haría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, una "tradicional" sería preguntar por la instancia de cada elemento de la lista, por ejemplo:

```
for (CuentaBancaria cb: cuenta) {
    if (cb instanceof CuentaCorriente) {
         CuentaCorriente cc = (CuentaCorriente)cb;
         // Aquí puedes trabajar con la instancia de CuentaCorriente
         // Para mostrarla o crear una nueva lista o lo que sea.
    } else if (cb instanceof CuentaCorriente) {
         CuentaAhorro ca = (CuentaAhorro)cb;
         // Aquí puedes trabajar con la instancia de CuentaAhorro
    }
}
```

Otra opción, compatible desde Java 8, sería crear una nueva lista "al vuelo" de una de las clases usando `Streams`, de esta forma:

```
List<CuentaCorriente > ctasCorriente = cuenta.stream()
         .filter(cta -> cta instanceof CuentaCorriente )
         .map(cta -> (CuentaCorriente )cta)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Si me permites un consejo, a las listas llámalas "listaDeAlgo" o usa un plural como "cuentas", resulta más intitutivo, de cara al mantenimiento posterior del código.

Comment: Wau muchisimas gracias! justo era eso!!! ya estaba pensando si modificar todo mi codigo y meterle dos arrayList diferentes pero si en un mismo arrayList se podian meter dos clases tenia que haber alguna manera de verlas por separado.